# roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch on multiple client

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Greetings.

I am using ROS Electric. I have three ROS station, one is master and other two are client machines. Each client machine has its own Kinect. Master's IP is configured as ROS_MASTER_URI on both clients. I also want to use /camera/rgb/image_color and /camera/depth/image_raw topics on both clients, published from their own kinect. Now the problem is, whenever I launch kinect using 'roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch', it stops the execution of the same launch file on the other client. Means, suppose I launch the kinect on client1, now if I try to launch the kinect of client2 on client2 by using the previous command, it stops the kinect of the first client, client1. I am stuck with this for awhile. Your help to solve this problem will be highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58217/roslaunch-openni_camera-openni_node.launch-on-multiple-client/) by [Tariq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4429/tariq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried :

- naming the différents nodes ?
- giving the topics differents names ?

Here is an example of what I do, with two kinects, on the same computer :

Parameters :

```
<arg name="camera1_id" default="#1" />
<arg name="camera2_id" default="#2" />
<arg name="depth_registration" default="true" />
<arg name="camera1_name" default="kinect1" />
<arg name="camera2_name" default="kinect2" />
```

Launching :

```
 <!-- Launching first kinect-->
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
    <arg name="device_id" value="$(arg camera1_id)" />
    <arg name="camera" value="$(arg camera1_name)" />
    <arg name="depth_registration" value="$(arg depth_registration)" />
 </include>
```

```
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
    <arg name="device_id" value="$(arg camera2_id)" />
    <arg name="camera" value="$(arg camera2_name)" />
    <arg name="depth_registration" value="$(arg depth_registration)" />
 </include>
```

By doing so, all the topics will appear in the namespace kinect1 and kinect2, for example topics : "kinect1/rgb/image_color", "kinect2/depth/image_raw", etc...

Have a nice day,

Bests regards,

Steph

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-03-15**:
Pay attention to the fact that my previous answer is using the new names in ROS Groovy. Thus, don't forget to change the name "openni_launch"' to "openni_camera" if you use Electric.

**Comment by [Tariq](https://answers.ros.org/users/4429/tariq/) on 2013-03-15**:
Thank you very much Stephane. It works :). I really appreciate it.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-03-15**:
Cool, happy to help :-) Don't forget to put my answer as correct then :-)